# WPF BackgroundWorker process RunWorkerCompleted is called multiple times, why?

Tags: wpf, backgroundworker, messagebox

I have some code that starts a background process for search in my WPF application:

```
 private void RunSearch(SearchArguments arguments)
    {
        _getSearchResults.DoWork += GetSarchFromDb;
        _getSearchResults.RunWorkerCompleted += SearchFinished;
        _getSearchResults.RunWorkerAsync(arguments);
    }
```

RunSearch is exicuted from button_click event.

I have a messagebox inside my SearchFinished method that shows "No Results Found". For some reason, the SearchFinished method is called multiple times sometimes, which causes multiple MessageBoxes to be shown. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: How many times is "multiple times"?

Comment: Looks like the answer may be here

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/7724ac95-a138-48ef-a208-dea0a566ada3

Comment: It goes up by 1 every time I press the button, that actually makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rushed the gun with posting this a bit.

Since I'm wiring up the events on button click, every time I click the button, the number of times the event executes goes up. I moved the wire up to the constructor, and my problem was fixed.

Comment: been bitten by this [figurative] bug many times myself. cases like these, it helps to have some logging - for instance you may have noticed a direct relation between number of executions and button clicks a little sooner ;)